# Adding class with jQuery only works for the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to code Darkmode on my website using jQuery and using `classList.toggle` to change colors. Everything is working fine for the most part, but navigation only works for the first `li` and `a`. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-darkmode">
    <div class="darkmode-definition">
        <button class="nightModeButton">darkmode</button>
    </div>


    <nav style="padding-left: 100px;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Galéria</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #171717;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

li a:hover {
    color: #171717;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body.night-mode {
    background: #181b23;
}

li a.night-mode {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
var nightModeToggleButton = document.querySelector(".nightModeButton");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var navigacka = document.querySelector("a");

nightModeToggleButton.onclick = function() {
    nightModeToggleButton.classList.toggle("night-mode");
    body.classList.toggle("night-mode");
    navigacka.classList.toggle("night-mode");
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing

```
li a.night-mode {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

to

```
.night-mode li a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

gives the result you are expecting.

**Just a thought:** Instead of applying color modifications directly on li or ul or a, have a class called `light-mode` maybe, and nest the styles associated to light-mode inside.

```js
var nightModeToggleButton = document.querySelector(".nightModeButton");
        var body = document.querySelector("body");
        var navigacka = document.querySelector("a");


        nightModeToggleButton.onclick = function() {
            nightModeToggleButton.classList.toggle("night-mode");
            body.classList.toggle("night-mode");
            navigacka.classList.toggle("night-mode");
        };
```

```css
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #171717;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

li a:hover {
    color: #171717;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body.night-mode {
    background: #181b23;
}

.night-mode li a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-darkmode">
            <div class="darkmode-definition">
                        <button class="nightModeButton">darkmode</button>
            </div>

 
 <nav style="padding-left: 100px;">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Galéria</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```